# Why this field extension has such basis?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Here is an argument for finding a basis for $\mathbb{Q}$.

> Since $X^2-2$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$,  $\{1,\sqrt{2}\}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}$-basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. Since $X^4-10X^2+1$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, $[\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}):\mathbb{Q}):\mathbb{Q}]=4$, hence $\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}\notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. Thus, $\sqrt{3}\notin \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. **Consequently, $\{1,\sqrt{3}\}$ is a $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$-basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2},\sqrt{3})$.**

I don't get the last sentence. I understand that $\sqrt{3}$ is not an element of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. Since $X^2-3$ is irreducible in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$, $\{1,\sqrt{3}\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{3})$, but how come the last assertion is true?

How do I know that $X^2-3$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$? Since the degree of polynomial is $2$ and $\sqrt{3}$ is not in $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$, this is irreducible over $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{2})$. I know that. But if the polynomial is not of degree 2, say $3^{1/4}$ rather than $\sqrt{3}$, is this argument still available? If so why?

Comment: To answer the second question: This argument works only because the degree of the polynomial is two. The minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{3}$ over $\mathbb Q$ is clearly $2$. The field $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ is greater (in terms of inclusion) than $\mathbb Q$. So the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt{3}$ over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$ can only be $1$ or $2$. It is $1$ if and only if $\sqrt{3}\in \mathbb Q(\sqrt{2})$. I guess it is obvious that this argument does not apply if the degree was greater than $3$, right?:)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very simply, $x^2-3$ is irreducible over $\mathbf Q(\sqrt 2)$ because it has no root in  $\mathbf Q(\sqrt 2)$: such a rot would be written as $a+b\sqrt 2\enspace (a, b \in\mathbf Q)$. Now

$$(a+b\sqrt 2)^ 2=3\iff a^2+2b^2+2ab \sqrt 2=3\iff\begin{cases}a^2+2b^2=3\\ab=0\end{cases}$$
since $(1,\sqrt 2)$ is a basis of $\mathbf Q(\sqrt 2)$ over  $\mathbf Q$.

Now this is impossible:

– if $a=0$, it implies $2b^2=3$ and $\sqrt 3$ would be rational.

– if $b=0$, it imples $a^2=0$ and  $\sqrt 3$ would again be rational.

Likewise , you can prove $(a+b\sqrt 2)^4=3$ implies $a=0$ or $b=0$, ans each cases would imply $\sqrt[4] 3$ is rational.

*Another argument* consists in observing $\sqrt[4]3 $ has degree $4$ over $\mathbf Q$, i.e. $$[\mathbf Q(\sqrt 3):\mathbf Q]=4 > [ \mathbf Q(\sqrt 2):\mathbf Q] ,$$ which is impossible if $\sqrt[4]3\in \mathbf Q(\sqrt 2)$

*A simple argument using the norm:*

If $x=\sqrt[r]3\in \mathbf Q(\sqrt 2)$, then $N(x)^r=N(x^r)=N(3)=9$ (of course here $N=N_{\mathbf Q(\sqrt 2)/\mathbf Q}$).

As $N(x)\in \mathbf Q$, this implies first $r=2$ (hence the case $r=4$ is impossible)  and
$N(x)=3$. Let$x=a+b\sqrt 2$. Then $N(x)=a^2-2b^2$; modulo $3$, the relation $a^2-2b^2=3$ becomes 
$$a^2+b^2=0.$$
Squares mod. $3$ are only $0, 1$ and it's easy to check that
$$a^2+b^2=0\iff a=b=0\pmod 3.$$
Thus $a$ and $b$ are divisible by $3$, which implies $3$ is divisible by $9$. This is again impossible.